# Postgresql and jsonb: perform a like over all values of an array

Tags: postgresql, json

Jsonb seems great but I can't figure out how to perform a partial search (like) over an array. In my case it's an array of email:

```
["email1@foo.com", "email2@foo.com", "email3@foo.com"]
```

I want to be able to get a record that has an email like "email2".

I tried the following

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE jsonb_array_elements(emails) like 'email2';
```

But it does not work (obviously).

If somebody can help... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT 
    id_user 
FROM
    users
    JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(emails) AS x(email) ON true
WHERE
    email::text like '%email%' ;
```

[`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) returns a [`SET OF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) [jsonb objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-json.html). You join them to user_id using a [`JOIN LATERAL`](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/join-lateral/). Then use a WHERE clause where you convert these jsonb objects to text, and then use your `like '%email%'`.

[You can check a simple setup at dbfiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=59ccdfd271ce8b78ab028f96639c86d7)

NOTE: If you do not want repeated values: `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You can use jsonb_array_elements_text to avoid the cast.